# Asking siri to remind me does not work any more

Tags: siri, reminders

When I ask Siri something like:

> "Remind me to ______ on Feb. ___"

It used to always add it to my reminders. Now it says I have to open the app for reminders. When I do that it still won't work with Siri. I have to add it manually.

As a teacher, I don't have time to add it manually with a class of students right in front of me. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried restarting my phone already.

Comment: I don't know what version of iOS you're using but it works fine for me on 17.1.1.